# Create a CardView with a semicircle on top

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, cardview

I am very much into designing a login screen.

Something like this:
[image]
How Do I actually cut the card from the top so as to fill the drawable on top of it? Any help would be of great value.

[Source: https://www.uplabs.com/posts/login-android-app/]

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do that. You have to implement it customly.

Comment: Can I create that shape via xml or Java?

Comment: Can you provide any link of tutorial ? That would be seriously great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit update from Ferdous Ahamed's answer. you need to make your image circular.

just add this to your gradle

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

then in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f36121">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:padding="24dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Login"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Sign In"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/profile_image"
         android:layout_width="96dp"
         android:layout_height="96dp"
         android:src="@drawable/profile"
         app:civ_border_width="2dp"
         app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

all you need to do is use same color. in your parent background and in your imageview use same color for border.

```
app:civ_border_color="#f36121"
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Refer Github [link](https://github.com/adityasd/LoginDemo).

Comment: Let me try your solution and will revert back to you!

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered!! Great Job! Aditya

Comment: @KARANCHAPANERI glad to help you. Happy Coding

Comment: what if the background has gradient and it is scrollable

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve almost similar by following:

1. Create a `RelativeLayout` as a container of `CardView` and `ImageView`
2. Set `card_view:cardElevation="0dp"` to show `ImageView` over `CardView`
3. On `ImageView`, set a `transparent circle image` for profile `Icon`.

**FYI,** If you want elevation for your `CardView`, 
set `CardView` elevation as`card_view:cardElevation="4dp"` and set `ImageView` elevation higher as`android:elevation="8dp"` to show `ImageView` over `CardView`.

**Here is the fully working code. Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#727272">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:padding="24dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Login"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="Sign In"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_circular_profile"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

**ICON:** I have used circular profile icon image from this [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=circular%20profile%20icon&client=ubuntu&hs=k7C&channel=fs&tbm=isch&imgil=MxudZ79j99TnyM%253A%253B7Ud9wXS6f7-agM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fcssdeck.com%25252Flabs%25252Fcss3icon%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=MxudZ79j99TnyM%253A%252C7Ud9wXS6f7-agM%252C_&usg=__FE__ZjFu1mGmIcmnWGHtBGlP5qw%3D&biw=1535&bih=805&ved=0ahUKEwiupJOVjYDTAhUMqY8KHUiED34QyjcIPQ&ei=dfXdWO6VEYzSvgTIiL7wBw#imgrc=MxudZ79j99TnyM:)

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: nice one layout +1

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan Thank you :). FYI, if your image is itself circular with transparent background then i think its not needed to use `circleimageview` library. But if you want to show any image with circle shape then we can use `circleimageview`.

Comment: yeah you are right. but questioner said 'How Do I actually cut the card from the top' so i thought we can achieve this like that way.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you..your solution also right. :)

Comment: it works great, but when I try to implement this in a dialog box view, I'm getting two layers of transparent background. any suggestions to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This screen is very complex in terms of what can be done with the current implementation of shapes and shadows on Android. It might actually be impossible to implement correctly using official libraries. You have to solve two problems - how to cut the view and how to provide a shadow for that view.

The support CardView's shadow is created using some kind of a gradient and supports only one case - the rounded rectangle. The Lollipop's shadow can take any shape as long as the shape is convex - which is not your case. As far as I know, there's no 3rd party library which could help you with that. You'd have to make your own shadow using RenderScript blur or just provide a background with a shadow.

It's possible to cut out the circular shape at the top. It requires some custom drawing/masking, but can be done pretty easily using standard Android library. You can do that using Canvas.saveLayer/restore() + PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR. More or less like this:

```
Path circle, card;
PorterDuffXfermode xfereMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
Bitmap avatar;

// make a layer to make cutting shapes possible
int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);

// draw the card and its content
canvas.drawPath(card, paint);
super.draw(canvas);

// clear the circular shape
paint.setXfermode(xfereMode);
canvas.drawPath(circle, paint);

// composite
canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
paint.setXfermode(null);

// draw the avatar
canvas.drawBitmap(avatar, x, y, paint);
```

It's not a compplete solution, but I hope you get the idea. To make a shadow, add a black filter, blur it with RenderScript and draw beneath the actual view.

It's a ton of work. Most likely will be very time consuming to implement correctly and very slow to execute. Layer composition and per-pixel operations are very slow even on modern desktop hardware.