# Custom shape for login

Tags: android, android-custom-view

Hi all am trying to create a view like this. I saw few SO question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117119/create-a-cardview-with-a-semicircle-on-top). But the background of circular imageview is filled with solid color I need it to be transparent. i.e, the rectangle needs to be made transparent where the circle come.

[image]

I tried making a vector and it look like this

[image]

Can somebody please help me with this.

EDIT :: 
I need the circle on top to be transparent and the rectangle below it should be transparent so that I could see he green background in between circle and curve in rectangle.

Comment: It should be provided by your designer

Comment: @AntonA. other than setting a background there is no option...? I asked because in the link it is achieved.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035902/how-to-create-transparent-semicircle

Comment: You need to make Custom view with path drawing.